# Boot a bricked s3 i535 for photo recovery

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, unbricking

I know I need an sdcard formatted a certain way with a factory image and it will go into a safe mode; question is, does anyone know where I can find instructions or can instruct me what file and how to do this?

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "bricked`?  Soft bricked?  If you just want to recover photos and not completely restore the phone, there are simpler ways.

Comment: Technically a hard brick. No Odin. Just that usb flag in device manager.

Comment: What model of S3?